# OrientDB Query full Graph without Edge Objects

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I want to know if there is a way I can Query the full Graph in OrientDB with `TRAVERSE * FROM V` without getting the Edges as Objects. Because with the References in all the Objects I get more than 50MB data from a 10 Vertex Graph. I use the [orientjs](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs) Driver.
My Data looks like this:
[image: OrientDB data]
I used the [Json-Stringify-Safe](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe) to convert the Json to a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
select *,out.asString(),in.asString() from (traverse *  from V) fetchplan [*] in_*:-2 out_*: -2
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain why you add the fetchplan at the end?

Comment: I add fetchplan to not show from Studio IN('myedge') and OUT("myedge") from the vertices as in the second query of Michela.
With NodeJS you can omit fetchplan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one to exclude the edges shown as records:

```
traverse * from V while @class NOT IN (select distinct(@class) from E)
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

You can use this one to exclude the edges from each record but it will show you the edges as records:

```
select from (traverse *  from V) fetchplan [*] in_*:-2 out_*: -2
```

[image]

And this is the mix of both queries:

```
select from (traverse * from V while @class NOT IN (select distinct(@class) from E)) fetchplan [*] in_*:-2 out_*: -2
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Your second Query executed in the OrientDB Studio is perfect, with the other two I dont get any Edges. But when i execute the second Query from my NodeJS Server, again I get References in the Edge Objects and 56MB of data.